# Duality while studying properties of an ensemble

Tags: einstein

Was Einstein the first to propose that observing an ensemble of N particles for time interval of dt is same as observing a single particle of ensemble for time interval of Ndt?

Comment: Welcome to History of Science and Mathematics. Your apparent assertion about Einstein is far from well known, and I never heard it. Do you have a citation to back it up? Or are you doubtful that Einstein proposed it and confirmation or dis-confirmation is part of your question? Please clarify.

Comment: I am not sure in what sense they are "the same", the distribution functions do not even have the same number of variables. Please clarify.

Comment: @Conifold perhaps he meant a single particle for N intervals of length dt, but it's still an odd question